# Running a VBS within a msi setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript, windows-installer

I am trying to create a setup for an application that I'm developing using the Visual Studio 2010 setup.
One of the things I need to do is run some exe programs. 
I am using a custome action to run a VBS.
This the method that im using to execute:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute """c:\prog.exe""","-parm bla" ,"","",""
```

The problem with this is that I cant wait for the program to finish using this method.
So I tried using this method:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "c:\prog.exe -parm bla",1,True
```

But is seems that when the MSI runs the script is dosnt have the WScript object.
So my question is can i somehow get acess to the WScript object from the MSI or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Ok i found a dirty workaround, I ran another script with cscript.exe and in that one i can use the WScript object.

Comment: Can't you add the execution to the customactions and insert it in the INstallExecuteSequence?

Comment: Probably could but I'd have to add cscript.exe to the installation package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you cannot use WScript object in scripts that are called by MSI. As a workaround what you can do is create a new custom action with Action = NewAction, type =38, Source = (blank) TArget = add the vb script file as TARGET by running the following commands 
CScript WiTextIn.vbs mymsi.msi CustomAction NewAction Target YourVBscript.vbs.

WiTextIn file is located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts

(PS: When you try to run VBScript it might fail because vbscripts are disabled and you might have to delete the key from registry and enable vbscript)

Comment: It seemed to work buy just adding the cscript.exe to my project then running a custom action with the script i want to run as a parameter, doing your way seems to eliminate the need to add the script to my project and will ensure that i use the current version of cscript that is on the os im installing on.

Comment: nopes you will not need csript to be on the OS you are installing, because the only time you are using cscript is when you insert the VB code in your MSI which is pre-installation process or MSi creation process. The command that i mentioned will enter the VB script code as plain text in TARGET column of CustomAction.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, Windows Installer does not support WScript objects directly. Have you tried to use the "CreateObject" function directly?

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: I agree with Bogdan's answer. My script when from not working to working.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did in my vbs script to open a firewall exception for the service. I couldn't use the standard interactive pop-up for a service (that asks for permission to open the firewall), since it doesn't have a UI.

```
set oShell  = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
oShell.run "cmd /C netsh advfirewall firewall add rule program=""C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\bar\prog.exe"" name=""my-service"" dir=in action=allow"
```

I added this vbs script to the "Commit" CustomAction of the Setup&Deployment Project, leaving the properties as defaults.

To debug problems with the vbs stage, I ran the msi from DOS using

```
msiexec /i mysetup.msi /L* install.log
```

Note that I originally used "Wscript.CreateObject" but that failed. This worked.